# Avoid ng-view getting "wiped" (updated) when $location.search updates GET params

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

So I have a map object instantiated using the leaflet library.  The map instance is created in a separate template and routed in this manner:-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui', 'ngResource']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/map.html',
        controller: 'MapCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
```

The problem begins when I want to handle "search/filtering" and control the GET params when searching against objects that I want loaded on the map instance.

Here's a simple filter function that I implemented and it gets triggered based on a selected value the user clicks on (in a dropdown list).

```
$scope.setFilter = function (fname, fvalue) {
    console.log("Setting " + fname + " to " + fvalue);
    var search_string = $location.search();
    search_string[fname] = fvalue;
    $location.search(search_string);
};
```

The browser address bar's url gets updated as I expect it to but the original (leaflet) map object gets "updated" and disappears from view. Which is not what I want.

How do I prevent this from happening or control this process so the map can still be seen?

Comment: Maybe you can try to trigger the redraw of the map every time when the filter is triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because updating the URL params triggers the route again and this is causing the controller to be reloaded. There is a simple fix for this. Use the property `reloadOnSearch` and set it to false. This will not reload the controller when the $location.search() changes

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'views/map.html',
         controller: 'MapCtrl',
         reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/',
         controller: 'MapCtrl',
         reloadOnSearch: false
    });

});
```

Comment: O gosh, I just discovered `reloadOnSearch: false` in the docs too!!!!!!!!!!! THANKS! :-D

Comment: Setting reloadOnSearch:false means that clicking a link with a different search term will do nothing.

Comment: well thats the intention in this case